# Eliminate doubles in a selected range upon open in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to build a macro that will run from opening a workbook , after that it will update data and after... will remove doubles from a selection but I don't know why is not working.

```
Sub Macro3()

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27    Range("A2:A352").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("Merge1[A2:A352]").RemoveDuplicates Header:= _
        xlYes
End Sub
```

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: At a guess, your headers are actually on row 1 not 2?

Comment: You also don't need `Range("A2:A352").Select`. Your statement after this statement negates the need for this statement. Infact, might be worth reading up on why we shouldn't use `Select` and `Activate` in VBA

Comment: Thanks , Yes my header is at row 1

Comment: But If I don't use Select how i can point the excel to eliminate de doubles for my selection?